# open custom ribbon in other workbook VBA

Tags: vba, ribbon

I am writing some vba in excel to create another excel report.
This report needs to have adjusted the header /footer, which my company have through their own custom ribbon in Office.

If I am in my main workbook, I am able to activate the ribbon by following code:

```
 Application.SendKeys ("%HY2%")
```

But after I created my excel report it seems like the custom ribbon is not given time to activate or something.

I then call the report like this
code:

```
 Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\ccc\sss.xlsx"
```

and then try
code:

```
 Application.SendKeys ("%HY2%")
```

Then it is possible to call the Home tab, but not the custom one.

I have tried to delay the code using wait function, sleep function and Do While (check if ready)

But during all these, it seems like excel tabs is on "hold", it is not activating the custom ribbon. Therefore my code opens the Hometab, but it cannot find "Y2" Ribbon.

I have tried activating the main workbook to do some random code, then going back again and activating the report again, but no...

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Vote to close this as too broad. Please narrow your question down to a single problem. Then provide the code you have tried (not as an image). Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: I have properly marked code samples to make the question more readable.

Comment: The Custom Ribbon will do nothing other than call a VBA macro in the host workbook.  Rather than trying to activate  a particular button on a Custom Ribbon you should see if you can call the macro directly from your code. If your company has created the custom ribbon then it seems reasonable that the relevant information should be easily available.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will look for the code behind. the custom ribbon is from an add-in i a .xlam file

Comment: I have now fixed it. I needed to use "OnTime" instead of "Wait" or "Sleep". Seems like "Ontime" was not blocking the custom Ribbons from loading. Thank you for all help.